# How do I create a directory in a given path in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I need to make a function that creates a directory in a subdirectory of the current location. Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <dir.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void create(){
    char nume[50];
    int directory1,directory2;
    directory1=mkdir("folder1");
    directory2=mkdir("/folder1/ name1");
}

int main()
{
    create();
}
```

When I run this code, the "folder1" directory does get created, but "name1" doesn't. What am I doing wrong? I also tried doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <dir.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void create(){
    char nume[50];
    system("mkdir folder1");
    system("mkdir /folder1/name1");
}

int main()
{
    create();
}
```

But I get a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" message.

Comment: ***What am I doing wrong?*** Looks like an extra space in the path. Did you want the second folder to be named " name1".  Also with the / you are putting it at the root of the fileseystem instead of a relative path.

Comment: `mkdir("/folder1/` didn't you mean `mkdir("folder1/`. I see `mkdir` takes two arguments: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html . Is it ok to pass one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the `<filesystem>` library which is available as of C++17, in this case using [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)

```
#include <filesystem>

void create()
{
    std::filesystem::path subfolder = "/folder1/name1";
    std::filesystem::create_directories(subfolder);
}

int main()
{
    create();
}
```

Note that `create_directory` assumes all parent directories exist, otherwise `create_directories` will create intermediate directories if missing.

Comment: I'm getting an "abort() has been called" debug error

Comment: @jasd I suspect the path should be "folder1/name1" rather than "/folder1/name1", right?  The abort is probably due to an uncaught permissions related exception.

Comment: @CoryKramer You're welcome, I removed my comment then ^^